# Custom Apache 404 page

Tags: apache2

I want to customise the 404 page of my Apache Webserver on Ubuntu to something other than the general:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /***** was not found on this server.
______________________________________________________

Apache/*.*.** (Ubuntu) Server at **** Port 80
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/apache/ht/ht404apache.htm is a short guide.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

You have to edit the file /etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages

```
sudoedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages
```

You can enter plaintext or link to a script or html

Answer (score 6):

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@host.ru
    ServerName host.ru
    ServerAlias www.host.ru
    DocumentRoot /home/WebServer/www/host.ru/public_html/
    ErrorLog /home/WebServer/www/host.ru/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/WebServer/www/hostu/logs/access.log combined


    Alias /error_html/ "/home/WebServer/www/host/error_html/"
    <Directory "/home/WebServer/www/host.ru/error_html">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /error_html/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. Hope it helps.

**[DEMO](http://subins.hp.af.cm/sdfvd)**

Go to your site's folder.

Create a file named **.htaccess** (just **.htaccess** no name only file extension).

Open the file and add the line.

> ErrorDocument 404 **/pathtofile**

Replace **/pathtofile** with your 404 page file name which should be situated in the same folder as the file **.htaccess** .
The custom **404** file can be in PHP or HTML.
You can also add HTML to it like this:

> ErrorDocument 404 '<h1>404 Not Found</h1>'

You don't have to reload Apache Server ! It's finished. Test it out.

Source - [Subin's Blog](http://sag-3.blogspot.in/2012/11/custom-404-page.html)

Comment: This would require "AllowOverride" config in apache to be on, which is not the default in ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

One kind of 404 customization (not yet covered here) is redirecting the 404 page in VPS Ubuntu to a separate page, such as the site's home page.

To do this, make a file called `.htaccess` in the web root and put this line in it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com
```

Then save the file.

This will make the 404 page redirect to the specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not customize default error messages of Apache 2.4 in any easy way because those messages are inside the `apache2` executable.

However, you can override them using "ErrorDocument" directives which can be used also in `apache2.conf`.

An even better way could be using `Include` in `apache2.conf` and collect overridden messages in one separate file.

Please also see the [Apache 2.4 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument).